# List SIM Info (Dual SIM device) for Android API 17 and up

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the SimInfo of a dual sim device using this content provider

```
public static List<SimInfo> getSIMInfo(Context context) {
    List<SimInfo> simInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
    Uri URI_TELEPHONY = Uri.parse("content://telephony/siminfo/");
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(URI_TELEPHONY, null,     "slot>=0", null, null);
    if (c!=null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            int id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            int slot = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("slot"));
            String display_name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("display_name"));
            String icc_id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("icc_id"));
            String number=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("number"));
            SimInfo simInfo = new SimInfo(id, display_name, icc_id, slot, number);
            Log.d("apipas_sim_info", simInfo.toString());
            simInfoList.add(simInfo);
        } while (c.moveToNext());


        c.close();
    }       

    return simInfoList;
}
```

it is working on API 17 but for API >=22 the Cursor returns null.